# Column: Trailing widget consumes entire tile width. Please use a sized widget, or consider replacing ListTile with a custom widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello trying to learn flutter and found this great open source project, trying to get it to run locally and running into the above issue. I think the offending code is the Column within the ListTile, but can't figure out the exact issue or how to resolve, I tried adding a width/height and converting column to a container, but I don't think I got the syntax correct. Any insight is appreciated!

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: usersRef.doc('$userId').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data;
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(documentSnapshot.data());

      return ListTile(
        contentPadding:
            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 5.0),
        leading: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                '${user?.photoUrl}',
              ),
              radius: 25.0,
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                ),
                height: 15,
                width: 15,
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: user?.isOnline ?? false
                          ? Color(0xff00d72f)
                          : Colors.grey,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                    ),
                    height: 11,
                    width: 11,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        title: Text(
          '${user.username}',
          maxLines: 1,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        subtitle: Text(
          type == MessageType.IMAGE ? "IMAGE" : "$msg",
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          maxLines: 2,
        ),
        trailing: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextTime(
              child: Text(
                "${timeago.format(time.toDate())}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  fontSize: 11,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 5),
            buildCounter(context),
          ],
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
            CupertinoPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Conversation(
                  userId: userId,
                  chatId: chatId,
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      return SizedBox();
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: try to adding `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` to your `BoxConstraints`

Comment: I realized I copied the wrong code, updated it now

Comment: Try adding fixed size for your `Column` in `trailing` property, either using `SizedBox` or `Container` as parent.

Comment: I tried adding SizedBox as parent, but that didn't work so I tried adding container with constraintBox, neither one worked, how do I know what to set for width/height?